# Can pandas infer the correct column when there are missing values?

Tags: pandas

I have a csv that's something like:

```
Name, State, Number, Date 
A, TX, 3, 1/31/2019
A, PA, 5, 2/14/2019
B, CA, 2, 1/15/2019
B, 1/16/2019
C, NY, 1, 4/30/2019
```

When pandas parses the file it looks like:

```
   Name    State  Number          Date
0   A         TX       3    2019-01-31
1   A         PA       5    2019-02-14
2   B         CA       2    2019-01-15
3   B  1/16/2019     NaN           NaT
4   C         NY       1    2019-04-30
```

Is there a  way to set it up such that the 4/30/2019 is moved to the Date column, and the null values are in the State and Number columns? Essentially, can pandas infer where the null values should go based on the types of the column? (Modifying the csv isn't an option, unfortunately.)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do I now B is Name and not a State?  Is this based on patterns?

Comment: malformed csv. change to: `B, , , 1/16/2019`